# Mail Form Pull Values from previous page

Tags: php, actionmailer, html-email

I have made a mail form like so

```
<?php

//session_start();


$Total = $_POST['Total'];
$room = $_POST['room'];
$letter = $_POST['letter'];
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Address = $_POST['address'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$body = "Message sent from CARBONYZED Quotation System | www.CARBONYZED.co.uk ".     "\r\n".
        "// Number of $room = Sel". $letter. " \r\n".
        "// Quote Total = ". $Total. " \r\n".                           
        "// Name = ". $Name. " \r\n".
        "// Email = ". $Email. " \r\n".
        "// Address = ". $Address. " \r\n".
        "// Message = ". $Message. " \r\n".

$subject = "**CONTACT FORM** - From CARBONYZED's Web Server";

      $to = "AffordableCleaners@carbonyzed.co.uk";
        $headers = 'AffordableCleaners@carbonyzed.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
      'Reply-To: AffordableCleaners@carbonyzed.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
      if (mail($to, $Email, $body, $headers)) {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>  Click here to go <a     href='http://www.affordablecleaners.co.uk'>back</a>");

    } else {
      echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
    }
       ?>
```

Which is great except I need to add some more functions. On the previous Page, I have a number of  boxes, which I will post here

```
<tr>
<td align="left">Stairs</td>
<td align="center" style="text-align: left">
<select name="SelA">
<option>0</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="TotA" onFocus="this.blur();" />
<br></td>
<td width="120" align="center" style="text-align: left">
<select name="SelAA">
<option>0</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="TotAA" onFocus="this.blur();" />
<br></td>
<td width="116" align="center" style="text-align: left">
<select name="SelUA">
<option>0</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="TotUA" onFocus="this.blur();" />
<br></td>


</tr>
```

**Please** can you help me do two things, firstly pull forward the  Stairs to send the content (e.g. Stairs) with the mail but also 3 values, the content for each of the  in each of the  drop downs...

Also, we may be adding a number of  all with similar data, but not identical. basically the name text value in th Stairs format will allways be random but the SelA and SelUA will always be changing. Basically we would need it to loop for everything between and pulling in these 4 bits of info (or 8, 12, 16...

Hope somebody's crazy brain can help

Regards

Henry

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Please give an example of selected fields and desired output. Is there a problem with just including these three extra input fields? It works the same as your existing text input.

Comment: My problem is that as the table is loaded from MySQL php on the previous page I might end up with an unknown number of drop down boxes, <select name="SelA"><select> <select name="SelAA"><select> <select name="SelUA"><select> and then <select name="SelB"><select> <select name="SelAB"><select> <select name="SelUB"><select> and then <select name="SelC"><select> <select name="SelAC"><select> <select name="SelUC"><select> etc... The Letter (A, B or C) in this case is a variable $letter in the previous pages php, so is it possible to make a loop for this?
 http://www.affordablecleaners.co.uk/quote/

Comment: as in my $body I need it to show every $Sel$Letter, $SelA$Letter and $SelU$Letter that appears. Not just one set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every form option from the previous page before the submit (whether it be POST or GET) will be included as it's name on the next page. Just like the statements at the top of your PHP, you can get the values of your boxes:

```
$SelA= $_POST['SelA'];
$SelAA= $_POST['SelAA'];
$SelUA= $_POST['SelUA'];
```

Then you can just use these values in the body like you already have:

```
$body = "Message sent from CARBONYZED Quotation System | www.CARBONYZED.co.uk ".     "\r\n".
        "// Number of $room = Sel". $letter. " \r\n".
        "// Quote Total = ". $Total. " \r\n".                           
        "// Name = ". $Name. " \r\n".
        "// Email = ". $Email. " \r\n".
        "// Address = ". $Address. " \r\n".
        "// Message = ". $Message. " \r\n".
        "// SelA= ". $SelA. " \r\n".
        "// SelAA= ". $SelAA. " \r\n".
        "// SelUA= ". $SelUA. " \r\n".
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: almost perfect @paronity


My only concern is that as the table is loaded from MySQL php on the previous page I might end up with an unknown number of drop down boxes,

`<select name="SelA"><select>
<select name="SelAA"><select>
<select name="SelUA"><select>` and then 
`<select name="SelB"><select>
<select name="SelAB"><select>
<select name="SelUB"><select>` and then
`<select name="SelC"><select>
<select name="SelAC"><select>
<select name="SelUC"><select>` 

etc...

The Letter (A, B or C) in this case is a variable $letter in the previous pages php, so is it possible to make a loop for this?

Comment: You can see the code at view-source:http://www.affordablecleaners.co.uk/quote/ Thanks

Comment: as in my $body I need it to show every $Sel$Letter, $SelA$Letter and $SelU$Letter that appears. Not just one set...

Comment: Then @mario's solution should work for you. Just name the field something unique from the database and it can be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your form page to throw the input fields in an array:

```
 <select name="Sel[A]">  ...
 <select name="Sel[AA]">  ...
 <select name="Sel[XA]">  ...
```

Then append those with a loop:

```
 foreach ($_POST["Sel"] as $key => $value) {

      $email_body .= "// Stairs? $Sel $key = $value \r\n";
 }
```

And yes, this is the non-cumbersome way to concatenate variables with strings.